# Making a count distinct pivot table from non-organized data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I know that similar questions have been asked but my problem isn't conected with DistinctCount function, more with data I want to use. I know that commonly pivot tables are made from data in tables, however this time I want to make it from non-organized data set and place it on the same sheet. Example (one column, every number in diffrent row):

```
3 
2
3
4
```

And I wanna get a pivot table with a count of difftent numbers:

| Number | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

I now how to made it with a data organize in table, and my code look like this:

```
Sub Task3()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range


Set Sheet = Worksheets("Data")

Set PRange = Sheet.Cells(2, 4).Resize(6, 4)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Sheet.Cells(23, 7), _
TableName:="TP")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=Sheet.Cells(23, 7), TableName:="TP")

With Sheet.PivotTables("TP").PivotFields("???")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With Sheet.PivotTables("TP").PivotFields( _
    "[Number].[Count]")
    .Caption = "Distinct Count"
    .Function = xlDistinctCount
End With

End Sub
```

I don't know how to replace column name in defining rows.

I will be greatful for any tips and ideas.

Comment: I don't know from vba, but when I want a count for all distinct values or numbers and have them in a pivot table, I just place that field (in your case 'Numbers') in the 'Rows' area (bottom left one)

Comment: Yes, and when making a pivot table with non-organized data I have no problem. But with a vba code I can't find any excample how to do this